Flutter iOS app error No such module 'GTMSessionFetcherCore'
Flutter iOS App No such module 'GTMSessionFetcherCore'

import FirebaseAppCheckInterop
import FirebaseAuthInterop
import FirebaseCore
#if COCOAPODS
  import GTMSessionFetcher
#else
  import GTMSessionFetcherCore
#endif 

I don't know why I keep getting this error the app was working fine
tried to
clean flutter
remove pods
deleted the iOS app and recreated it
but nothing is working

I fixed this issue by changing my pod file by this one
Podfile link
then pod install
run
